# Backbone.js - model set during change

Tags: backbone.js

I'd like to do model.set(...) during the "change" event - some model attributes must be in sync: e.g. I have a budged that can cover a number of products but if I change the budget, the number of products must be updated and vice-versa. I've tried disabling the "change" event (i.e. model.off('change');) and then enable it after model.set(...), i.e. model.on('change', callbackFunction); , but I the change event handler/callback is still called.

What is the best approach for updating the model in the changed handler/callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `options` object with silent flag

```
this.model.set({someKey:25}, {silent: true});
```

There would be no `change` event

Comment: The change is handler still is being called.

Comment: I am referring to something else.. in the testMdl.on('change', function() { ... }); do a testMdl.set(...); => during change, I want to set some other attribute of the model and not cause the fire of the 'change' event. Now, I get a infinite loop because set cause a change which causes the change handler/callback to be called.

Comment: You can use more specific event `change:someKey` and set other `someKey2` during it with no loop

Comment: and if I call set on someKey1 on change:someKey2, I get the same loop.  So, there's no way to update the model during chage?

Comment: {silent: true} - еhis should shut down all events regarding changes of 'set' method... just use it inside of change event handler

Comment: Yes, indeed you are correct! http://jsfiddle.net/LHcQu/5/ - I am also using Backbone.ModelBinder so I guess this triggers a change also.

Answer (score 1):

You can control setting the model and be "silent" about it. So if you want to set something and make it NOT call change you need to add `silent: true` for example:

```
model.set('budget', '$12.34', { silent: true })
```

Also you can be specific on the `change`.  So say one of your other models needs to listen to only the "budget total" for example. You just listen to the change of the budget total:

```
modelOne.listenTo( modelTwo, 'change:budgetTotal', function( modelTwo, value ){ 
  this.set('budgetTotal', value ); 
});
```